# How to convert dictionary in desired format to specified Json format like Key value pairs as given below?

Tags: python, json, flask

I want to convert this dictionary to expected output in json format

```
sample_dict = {"app":"Apps","dev":"Dev-Func","test":"Testing"}

output = 
{"name":[
    {"option":"app", "value":"Apps"},
    {"option":"dev", "value":"Dev-Func"},
    {"option":"test", "value":"Testing"}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list comprehension over the dict items to convert to the format you want. Then use Flask's `jsonify` function to return a JSON response.

```
from flask import jsonify

output = {'name': [ {'option': k, 'value': v} for (k, v) in sample_dict.items()]}
return jsonify(output)
```